# Applying Kullback-Leibler (aka kl divergence) element-wise in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two tensors named `x_t`, `x_k` with follwing shapes `NxHxW` and `KxNxHxW` respectively, where `K`, is the number of autoencoders used to reconstruct `x_t` (if you have no idea what is this, assume they're `K` different nets aiming to predict `x_t`, this *probably* has nothing to do with the question anyways) `N` is batch size, `H` matrix height, `W` matrix width.

I'm trying to apply [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) algorithm to both tensors (after broadcasting `x_t` as `x_k` along the `K`<sup>th</sup> dimension) using [Pytorch's `nn.functional.kl_div`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.kl_div) method.

However, it does not seem to be working *as I expected*. I'm looking to calcualte the `kl_div` between each observation in `x_t` and `x_k` resulting in a tensor of size `KxN` (i.e., `kl_div` of each observation for each `K` autoencoder).

The actual output is a *single value* if I use the `reduction` argument, and the same tensor size (i.e., `KxNxHxW`) if I do not use it.

Has anyone tried something similar?

---

Reproducible example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
#                  K   N   H  W
x_t = torch.randn(    10, 5, 5)
x_k = torch.randn( 3, 10, 5, 5)

x_broadcasted = x_t.expand_as(x_k)

loss = F.kl_div(x_t, x_k, reduction="none") # or "batchmean", or there are many options
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear to me what exactly constitutes a probability distribution in your model. With `reduction='none'`, `kl_div`, given `log(x_n)` and `y_n`, computes `kl_div = y_n * (log(y_n) - log(x_n))`, which is the "summed" part of the actual Kullback-Leibler divergence. Summation (or, in other words, taking the expectation) is up to you. If your point is that `H, W` are the two dimensions over which you want to take expectation, it's as simple as

```
loss = F.kl_div(x_t, x_k, reduction="none").sum(dim=(-1, -2))
```

Which is of shape `[K, N]`. If your network output is to be interpreted differently, you need to better specify which are the event dimensions and which are sample dimensions of your distribution.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience of not stating which tensors represent probabilities. `.sum(dim=(-1, -2))` answers the question; that is, element-wise function applying. Thank you.